# Ruby on Rails uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I get this error after trying to save a file.

> undefined method `original_filename' for "Screenshot from 2017-08-26 22-12-42.png":String

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

And that's my request parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"JqTuIpsrX/rfJ2/r74EbLjuWI/UlxpxpEWnX64ruRjO/UQfrDk/q/MhVLNOG16YJOBxmt84t4tfw4YZDFbRIzQ==",
 "description"=>{"position"=>"5", "title"=>"title", "short_description"=>"qweqwe", "long_description"=>"qweqwe"},
 "photos"=>{"photo"=>"Screenshot from 2017-08-26 22-12-42.png"},
 "button"=>""}
```

Comment: Your request parameters doesn't contain the file (`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`) object. You are uploading the file incorrectly.

Comment: Could you tell me which information you need to fix this issue, or useful documentation please. I have used this guide"http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files".

Comment: Thanks  @iddorails, you put me in the right road.

Comment: Glad I could help :) All the best with your Rails journey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank @kiddorails for his help.

The documentation  here is pretty clear " http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files", the problem was in view file where I haven't put below helper inside the form,

```
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
```

as show in the documentation.

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using carrierwave to perform file upload. The way to use it is supremely simple, and has different tools for its handling.

You can implement this gem with the following guide:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-carrierwave-with-devise

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm new in ROR so I'm trying to involve in this framework as possible.

Comment: Follow the guide, is very easy to implement.